# Using -e and -s switch in perl

Tags: perl

I am starting to lern Perl. I tried

```
perl -e 'print "The value of \$x=$x\n";'
```

gives:

```
The value of $x=
```

whereas:

```
perl -s -x=10 -e 'print "The value of \$x=$x\n";'
```

gives

```
No Perl script found in input
```

I would like to use the `-s` switch together with `-e` switch.. Why is it not working?

Comment: Hey Mate, if you'd like some more general coding feedback outside of the scope of the questions that you've asked, you can contact me at `print 'X'x17^',50v;(96x9,x?5914'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arguments to the script itself should come *after* the script, regardless of whether it's a one-liner or a file. While not always necessary, you can separate the arguments for perl from the arguments to your script with a `--`:

```
$ perl -s -E'say "\$x=$x"' -- -x=42
x=42
```

Ending the arguments to perl with `--` is necessary because `-x` is a flag understood by perl itself, so your script would never see it. From [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-x*):

> #### -x
>
> #### -xdirectory
>
> tells Perl that the program is embedded in a larger chunk of unrelated text, such as in a mail message.  Leading garbage will be discarded until the first line that starts with "#!" and contains the string "perl".  Any meaningful switches on that line will be applied.
>
> […]
>
> If a directory name is specified, Perl will switch to that directory before running the program.  The -x switch controls only the disposal of leading garbage.  The program must be terminated with "**END**" if there is trailing garbage to be ignored;  the program can process any or all of the trailing garbage via the "DATA" filehandle if desired.
>
> The directory, if specified, must appear immediately following the -x with no intervening whitespace.

As the specified input `print "The value of \$x=$x\n";` does not contain a shebang, the actual script wasn't found and thus the error you encountered was emitted.

Do not use `-s` switch parsing for any but the most simple one-liners. Use [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -se 'print "The value of \$x=$x\n";' -- -x=10
```

[perlrun documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-s%2a) could be more clear on this option,

> -s
>   enables rudimentary switch parsing for switches on the command line after the program name but before any filename arguments (or before an argument of --). Any switch found there is removed from @ARGV and sets the corresponding variable in the Perl program. The following program prints "1" if the program is invoked with a -xyz switch, and "abc" if it is invoked with -xyz=abc.