# How to pass both variables and files to a perl -p -e command

Tags: perl, file, shell, unix

I have a command line written in perl that executes in Solaris (maybe this is irrelevant as it is UNIX-like) which **inserts a "wait" string every 6 lines**

```
perl -pe 'print "wait\n" if ($. % 6 == 0);' file
```

However, I want to replace that 6 by a parameter (ARGV[0]), resulting in something like this:

```
perl -pe 'print "wait\n" if ($. % ARGV[0] == 0);' file 6
```

It goes well, giving me the right output, until it finishes reading the file and treats "6" as the next file (even when it understood it as `ARGV[0]` before).

Is there any way to use the `-p` option and specify which parameters are files and which ones are not?

---

Edited: I thought there was a problem with using the `-f` option but as @ThisSuitIsBlackNot pointed out, I was using it wrongly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `-f`? I don't think it does what you think it does. See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-f*).

Comment: I see, you are right I thought it was for reading from a file. However, I'll modify the question because it is not the cause. Thanks

Comment: Can you pass the file in via stdin and pass your argument in as ARGV[0]?

Comment: I tried to read from stdin but stills trying to make sense of the number as a file.

I tried the solution of Arunesh but tries to recognize both, -- and -=5 as files

Comment: @Nilox  Pass `ARGS` before file `perl -spe 'print "wait\n" if (($. % $arg)==0);' -- -arg=6 file`. Sorry this will work, I was not on `perl` before.

Comment: See also [Using -e and -s switch in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496063/using-e-and-s-switch-in-perl)

Comment: @AruneshSingh It was that. Useful solution, thanks

Comment: always enable warnings, even (tempted to say especially) in oneliners

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-p`, as a superset of `-n`, wraps the code with a `while (<>) { }` loop, which reads from the files named on the command line. You need to extract the argument before entering the loop.

```
perl -e'$n = shift; while (<>) { print "wait\n" if $. % $n == 0; print }' 6 file
```

or

```
perl -pe'BEGIN { $n = shift }  print "wait\n" if $. % $n == 0' 6 file
```

Alternatively, you could also use an env var.

```
N=6 perl -pe'print "wait\n" if $. % $ENV{N} == 0' file
```

Comment: That BEGIN was just the thing I needed. It solved the problem and many more in the future. Thanks