# Why is the escape of quotes lost in this regex substitution?

Tags: regex, bash, perl

Why is the escaping of double quotes are lost in this case?

```
$ cat foo.txt   
This is a \"very good\" text worth AMOUNT dollars    
$ cat full_story.txt   
This is about money:  
STORY
```

Testing it with the following:

```
VAR=$(cat foo.txt)                                                                                         
TOTAL=$(cat full_story.txt)  
echo "$TOTAL" | perl -pe "s/STORY/$VAR/g"
```

Result:

```
This is about money:  
This is a "very good" text worth AMOUNT dollars
```

The escape of double quotes got lost. I was expecting:

```
This is about money:  
This is a \"very good\" text worth AMOUNT dollars
```

How can I preserve the escapes?

Comment: double up your backslashes or quote the text in `foo.txt` like `"This is .."`.

Comment: @keithpjolley:1) Quoting the `This is...` still removes the escapes. Also it is not what I want as I don't what that line quoted 2) Doing double escapes solves this but I would prefer to not do that as the copy had the escapes already

Comment: @keithpjolley: +1 the double escaping works though. I would like to understand why the approach is not working

Comment: this just used up the last little bit of perl knowledge in my head:  `echo "$TOTAL" | perl -pe '$v=q{'"$VAR"'};s/STORY/$v/g'`.  I'm sure there are different ways of doing this that make more sense.

Comment: Don't try to generate Perl code from the shell! You are likely to do it wrong, and indeed you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code suffers from a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug. Specifically, you're trying to generate Perl code from the shell, but failing at it.

You are passing the following to Perl:

```
s/STORY/This is a \"very good\" text worth AMOUNT dollars/g
```

You should be passing the following:

```
s/STORY/This is a \\"very good\\" text worth AMOUNT dollars/g
```

---

To properly generate Perl code, you'd need something like the following:

```
perl -pe's/STORY/'"$( printf %s "$VAR" | sed 's/\W/\\&/g' )"'/'
```

This passes the following to Perl (which is also fine):

```
s/STORY/This is a \\\"very good\\\" text worth AMOUNT dollars/g
```

---

It's far simpler to avoid generating Perl code in the first place, though. There are three primary ways of passing information to Perl without using STDIN or external storage.

- Arguments

  ```
  perl -pe'BEGIN { $VAR = shift(@ARGV) } s/STORY/$VAR/g' -- "$VAR"
  ```
- Command-line options

  In a full program, you'd use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long), but [`perl -s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will do fine here.

  ```
  perl -spe's/STORY/$VAR/g' -- -VAR="$VAR"
  ```
- Environment variables

  ```
  VAR="$VAR" perl -pe's/STORY/$ENV{VAR}/g'
  ```

Comment: Amazing! One question: Basically if I had `\\"very good\\"` in the text all these would be unnecessary?

Comment: So you're suggesting putting a fragment of Perl code --not even a complete token!-- in your data file. That's asking for trouble, and it's a horrible idea. I've said the following a few times already, but it doesn't seem to have sunk in: **Don't try to generate Perl code from the shell!**

Comment: Wait. You mean `\\"very good\\"` is perl code? Ah I see now. I didn't understand it

Comment: It seems that this `VAR="$VAR" perl -pe's/STORY/$ENV{VAR}/g'` works only if the substitution is within single quotes. This does not work `VAR="$VAR" perl -pe "s/STORY/$ENV{VAR}/g"`. Why?

Comment: Also this works: `VAR1="$VAR"  VAR2="$FOO" perl -pe's/$ENV{VAR1}/$ENV{VAR2}/g'. Is this correct usage or you see a misuse?

Comment: Depends if `VAR1` is a regex pattern, or a text string to match literally. It's likely the latter, so you've just introduced a new code injection. You need to convert the text into a regex: `perl -pe's/\Q$ENV{VAR1}/$ENV{VAR2}/g'`

Comment: But why with double quotes the snippet does not work? I mean this `VAR="$VAR" perl -pe "s/STORY/$ENV{VAR}/g"`

Comment: Do `printf '%s\n' "s/STORY/$ENV{VAR}/g"` and see what you're passing to Perl. Hint: It's not `s/STORY/$ENV{VAR}/g` as it should be!

Comment: I get `-bash: print: command not found`. Do you mean `printf`?

Comment: yup, typo (fixed)

Comment: By switching to double quotes, you made `$` special to the shell.

Comment: That prints `s/STORY/{VAR}/g`. So the shell tries to interpolate `$ENV` instead of passing it to perl and since it is not set we end up with `{VAR}`. Have I got it?

Comment: Exactly. . . . .

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `perl` parses backslash escapes in an explicit  replacement string (not a `perl` variable), and hence a `\"` is parsed into a`"`. For example:

```
$ echo "A STORY" | perl -pe 's/STORY/\"Hello\"/'
A "Hello"
```

(Note that the Bash variable `$VAR` does not become a `perl` variable `$VAR` , but rather a constant string.) So you need to escape the backslashes like this in constant string:

```
$ echo "A STORY" | perl -pe 's/STORY/\\"Hello\\"/' 
A \"Hello\"
```

You can work around the issue by transferring the Bash variable `$VAR` into a `perl` variable `$VAR` by using the [`-s`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) switch to `perl` like this:

```
echo "$TOTAL" | perl -spe 's/STORY/$VAR/g' -- -VAR="$VAR"
```

**Ouput**:

```
This is about money:  
This is a \"very good\" text worth AMOUNT dollars
```

Explanation:

- **-s** enables switch parsing for user defined switches on the `perl` command line. Any switch found there is removed from `@ARGV` and sets the corresponding variable in the Perl program.

Comment: Another workaround would be to say: `echo "$TOTAL" | perl -pe "s'STORY'$VAR'g"` so the `REPLACEMENT` is literally parsed.

Comment: @tshiono Thanks, great observation. I have edited your suggestion into my answer.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Very helpful! In the `-- -VAR="$VAR"` why is the dash in front of `VAR` needed? I.e. why is it not `-- VAR="$VAR"`? I could not understand from the doc you pasted that it is supposed to be like that

Comment: Yes I also think the documentation is not very clear at thant point. For more information, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496197/2173773) answer. So I think the dashes are needed to separate the `-VAR` and other user switches from ordinary `perl` options. I tested it a little bit, and you can even mix in ordinary arguments (`@ARGV`) by adding another instance of `--` like this: `perl -sE 'say ":ARGV=", join "|", @ARGV; say "VAR=$VAR"' -- -VAR=ss -- 1 2 3`

Comment: @ikegami Good catch! So then the first approach using `-s` would be a more correct approach than the second not using `-s`?

Comment: @tshiono, `perl -pe "s'STORY'$VAR'g"` still suffers from an injection bug like the OP's. In your case, it mishandles `\\ ` and `\'`. Don't generate Perl code from the shell!